# Parsing a JSON string as part of an http request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using a BehaviorSubject in Angular to fetch some event data and display it to the page. As part of my method that retrieves the data, I apply the following transformation to parse some data stored in a JSON string:

```
return this.http
  .get(url)
  .map(response => {
    return response.json().data
      .map(ge => ge.data = JSON.parse(ge.details));
  });
```

The app retrieves the objects, but it appears as if the data attribute is being populated after the page is rendered. I have some content that is conditionally displayed with `*ngIf='ge.data'` and it does not display. The data attribute, however, is present when I log the objects to the console at various points in the process.

My question boils down to this: What's the best way to parse data stored as a JSON string so that it's immediately usable in my Angular application?

Comment: Please read the documentation more carefully. `response.json()` returns a **promise** which you must wait on, as in `.map(response => response.json()).map(ge => ge.data = ge.details).

Comment: @torazaburo Do you have a documentation reference for that? [`Response`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/http/src/static_response.ts#L37-L100) doesn't implement `json`; it's in [`Body`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/http/src/body.ts#L23-L36) and it does not appear to involve a promise. It's obtained from the `ResponseOptions`, where it's [declared as `string|Object|ArrayBuffer|Blob|null`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/http/src/base_response_options.ts#L46-L49).

Comment: you can go wtih something like `*ngIf = ge?.data`

Comment: The example in the docs using `response.json().data` is preceded by a `toPromise()`.

Comment: @torazaburo In [the example](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-hero-by-id), `toPromise` is called on the returned observable, not on the `Response` emitted by the observable. The promise resolves when the observable completes - having emitted the `Response` - by which time the body is available; `json()` is a synchronous method that returns the parsed body.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I had some syntax issues with the second map, because it appears to work as I had expected when I pull the logic in the second map into it's own method like so:

```
http.get(url)
  .map(response => response.json().data
    .map(this.decode));

decode(inData: dataObj): dataObj{
  inData.data = JSON.parse(inData.details);
  return inData;
}
```

Comment: That's because now you're actually returning the data that binds to the template.  You really should be using `subscribe()` function to perform any assignment or data transformations.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not with parsing the JSON.
The problem is that you are sending an ajax request and expecting to have the result immediately.
By definition an ajax call is being processed without blocking the rendering of the page and fire callback/return promise when done.
If you want to perform logic like update image based on the response you should perform this logic within the callback of the ajax call or by using the `then()` method of the promise.